# Adding colors in python interpreter prompt, does not wrap properly

Tags: bash, python

I would like to have a more colorful Python prompt in the terminal, just for readability.  I currently have:

```
sys.ps1 = '\033[96m>>> \033[0m'
sys.ps2 = '\033[96m... \033[0m'
```

in my `PYTHONSTARTUP` file, which does give it colors as desired.  However, any text over a line does not wrap properly.  The text goes to the end of the line, and instead of immediately starting a new line, starts overwriting the beginning of the first line before starting a new line.  As you might imagine, this is actually rather unreadable.  How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sys.ps1 = '\001\033[96m\002>>> \001\033[0m\002'
sys.ps2 = '\001\033[96m\002... \001\033[0m\002'
```

[This answer to a similar question explains why the `\001` and `\002` are necessary.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9468954/505154)

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that question earlier.  Thanks, that fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

Is there some reason to not use [IPython](http://ipython.org/)? IPython does provide color prompts, etc. out of the box...

Comment: woah, didn't know about that.  I don't particularly care for the interface, but thanks for the tip!