# Randomly change the prompt in the Python interpreter

Tags: python, prompt, python-interactive

It's kind of boring to always see the `>>>` prompt in Python. What would be the best way to go about randomly changing the prompt prefix?

I imagine an interaction like:

```
This is a tobbaconist!>> import sys
Sorry?>> import math
Sorry?>> print sys.ps1
Sorry?
What?>>
```

Comment: Just make sure you change it back before asking questions that include interpreter sessions...

Comment: @jonrsharpe *"Why isn't my interpreter a tobbaconist!?"*

Comment: On the contrary, I think about making the questions stand out even more by using colors in the prompt (e.g. sys.ps1 = '\033[01;31mwhat?>>>\033[00m ')

Comment: You could even have random colours to go with the tobacconist.

Comment: If you're changing the prompt colour and using readline, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468435/look-how-to-fix-column-calculation-in-python-readline-if-use-color-prompt) question.

Comment: Paging @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Yes, this might make his nipples explode with delight.

Comment: It might be a good idea to keep all of your random prompts a fixed width. Unless you like the extra challenge of counting your spaces  and ignoring when things don't look lined up to make sure you indent properly.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html?highlight=sys#sys.ps1), if you assign a non-string object to `sys.ps1` then it will evaluate the `str` function of it each time:

> If a non-string object is assigned to either variable, its str() is
>   re-evaluated each time the interpreter prepares to read a new
>   interactive command; this can be used to implement a dynamic prompt.

Well now it's obvious, you should make it dynamic! Make an object with a `__str__` method where you can place any logic you want:

```
class Prompt:
    def __str__(self):
        # Logic to randomly determine string
        return string
```

You can also make changes or insert things into this class as you go too. So for example, you could have a list of messages in `Prompt` that you append to, or change, and that will affect the console message.

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import random
>>> class RandomPrompt(object):
...     prompts = 'hello >', 'hi >', 'hey >'
...     def __repr__ (self): return random.choice(self.prompts)
... 
>>> sys.ps1 = RandomPrompt()
hello >1
1
hi >2
2
```

Comment: `__repr__()` or `__str__()`?

Comment: @glglgl, the prompt is generated by calling `__str__()`. If it's not defined, it defaults to `__repr__()` so in this case it doesn't matter which.

Comment: Just to be sure: why would you want to write a class in this example. Wouldn't `def RandomPrompt(): prompts = [...]; return choice(prompts)` suffice?

Comment: A function would run the initialization every time. In this particular case it wouldn't be expensive but it's generally a good practice to divide the initialization from the actual code.

Answer (score 19):

For changing the prompt, we use

```
>>>import sys
>>>sys.ps1 = '=>'
=>
```

Now the way to do it randomly would be something like this:

```
import random
import sys

random_prompts = ['->', '-->', '=>', 'Hello->']
sys.ps1 = random.choice(random_prompts)
```

To execute this  when your python interpreter starts, you can follow this guide: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/appendix.html#the-interactive-startup-file

Answer (score 8):

Nice question. The `>>>` prompt is in `sys.ps1`, the `...` in `sys.ps2`. The next question would be how to change this randomly. Just as a demonstration of changing it by hand:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.ps1 = '<<<'
<<<sys.ps1 = '<<< '
<<< sys.ps2 = '.?. '
<<< for i in line:
.?.
```