# How to copy/paste to/from Python console without prompt (">>>" and "...") causing SynthaxError

Tags: python

I've always found this very annoying that whenever IDLE code is posted online it contains the ">>>" and "..." characters and is essentially impossible to copy/paste easily without prior clean up.

Is there easy way to get around that from either the code poster and, more importantly for me, the code user's perspective?

The question marked as a possible duplicate asks how to change the prompt in the console. What I'm asking rather is, when I'm copy/pasting code into my console such as the code below:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
```

How can I do so without running into the problem of my console saying

```
  File "<input>", line 1
    >>> import os
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Python interactive prompt ">>>"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683744/change-python-interactive-prompt)

Comment: I always appreciate the prompt myself, because it lets me know what was input and what was output.

Comment: I usually only use the interactive console when I want to show specifically "when I input this, I get that". The prompts are helpful there for visually separating input from output. If there's significant setup code, like functions, I'll compose that in a file and F5 it over to the interactive console.

Comment: You could write a quick function to strip the prompt using the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python. I'm partial to my own answer to that question of course, but there are many to choose from.

Comment: If you're using a Windows *Powershell* or *Cygwin* terminal, you can just select the text using block-mode select, holding down `ALT`, while selecting the rectangular block and thus avoiding the REPL prompts. This should also work in *nix, but haven't tried it lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jacob's answer is a correct when it comes to posting console code.

However, for pasting console code into your own console it turns out that **IPython** which ships with the Anaconda distribution does not get tripped up over the '>>>' and '...' from IDLE console code:

```
In[7]: >>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
Out[7]: 'C:\\Projects\\xlsparser'
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a quick [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anowlcalledjosh/full/bgmmwz/) to do this – it very naively replaces all initial ">>> " or "... " sequences with nothing. Alternatively, you could use the following Python code:

```py
import re
def remove_prompts(code):
    print(re.sub("^(>{3}|\.{3})( |$)", "", code, flags=re.M))
```

For example:

```
>>> remove_prompts("""
... Here's some code:
... >>> def foo():
... ...     return "bar"
... ...""")

def foo():
    return "bar"

>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sys.ps1`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=ps1#sys.ps1) and `sys.ps2` to override the primary and secondary prompt of the interpreter.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.ps2 = '' # removing the secondary prompt '... '
>>> sys.ps1 = '' # removing the primary prompt '>>> '
1 + 3
4
(1 +
3
) 
4
```

Otherwise, you can use a text editor to remove the leading `>>>` and `...` prompts.

(vim: `:%s/^\(>>>\|\.\.\.\) //`)

Comment: This will be very useful when I'm copy/pasting my own console code. However, how about when copy pasting someone else's console code, that doesn't have the `ps2` and `ps1` deactivated (aside from manually cleaning the code myself in a text editor)?