# In Pycharm, 'Python Console" prompter was '>>>', but some how it changed to 'In[2]". Why does it happen?

Tags: pycharm

As in the title, in the `python console` in **PyCharm**, the prompter is changed from `>>>` to `In[2]`.

I do not understand what changed it, and how to get back to `>>>`.

[image]

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683744/change-python-interactive-prompt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have IPython installed. It changes the prompt. Either uninstall it or disable **Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Console | Use IPython if available** in PyCharm.