'In' and 'Out' missing in Jupyter
Just using Jupyter for the first time.
I have noticed that the the abbreviation 'In' (for input) and 'Out' (for Output) is missing to the left of the code line (please see picture). I am only getting the number in the brackets and not the 'In' or 'Out' screen image
Is there a setting?
Tried searching but did not find an answer

How are you running Jupyter? Are you running a jupyter notebook or jupyter lab? Are your running in a browser or something like VS Code? ``jupyter labseems to not bother with theIn:` in the input cell prompt.

Hi Matt, thanks for you mail. I don't know but I downloaded Anaconda and installed Jupyter that way. AFAIK it is a Jupiter Notebook I am coding on. I have seen some videos and the people have 'In' and 'Out' next to the lines of code and their output

If you don't have In:  and Out: that's not a problem, so unless you'd like to see them for aesthetic reason it's not a problem.

In IPython/jupter you can use, e.g., Out[1] (i.e. the output of input cell 1) as a variable, but this is very bad practice, so it might be that In:  and Out:  on the displayed prompts has been removed to discourage users from doing this (my idle speculation!)

If you do want to look at different ways to change the prompt stylings you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683744/change-python-interactive-prompt. (Although in jupyter lab the sys.ps1 value does still contain In: [], it just doesn't display the In:  in the browser!)

Thanks.  I think I would like it not just for aesthetics but hopefully I can follow the code better. Do you know how I can tell if it is Jupyter Lab or Jupyter notebook  I am using?  On your Jupyter notebook do you have the In: and Out:?

Did you launch it through Anaconda Navigator? If so, there may have been separate Jupyter notebook and Jupyterlab launch icons (see this image). If you're using jupyterlab it will look like this, whereas a plain Jupyter notebook will look like this. That said, the change in prompt output may be a new(ish) feature that is jupyter-wide.

This was cross-posted without linking here, and I have answered it there with references and options spelled out.

This question is similar to: New Jupyter Notebook Interface. And I voted to close it. Granted the title here makes it clearer by pinpointing one of the several differences in the newer interface design.

Thanks all. So are you both saying that it has been removed in the latest edition?
