# buggy ANSI escape sequences in R prompt

Tags: r, command-prompt, ansi-escape

When R is run interactively in a terminal which supports colors, it is possible to use ANSI escape sequences in order to put colors in the prompt, such as

```
options(prompt = "\033[0;31mThis is red\033[0m> ")
```

[image]

Unfortunately, something goes wrong because for long command lines, the line continuation override the prompt instead of being written in the next line.
[image]
The problem gets worse when using several colors, because somehow each escape sequence "takes up some space" in the command line, *up to the point that the end of the prompt might overwrite the beginning*. On my configuration this happens with for instance

```
options(prompt = paste("\033[0;31m With \033[0;32m multiple",
                   "\033[0;33m colors \033[0;34m this",
                   "\033[0;35m gets \033[0;36m really",
                   "\033[0;37m wrong! \033[0m"))
```

[image]

Why is it so? Is there a workaround?

PS: This rather old post seems related http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Xterm-escape-sequences-in-Prompt-td906375.html

*update:* with R version 3.6.0 and readline 8.0 (don't know which matters here), most of the above described problem disappeared, but some strange behaviors remain. Accepted answer below resolves everything.

Comment: To be clear, this is when your typing causes a new line, not when you break a long line and get a continuation prompt, usually "+" yeah? Screenshots might help (and are encouraged here, unlike on R-help!)

Comment: @Spacedman Exactly, this is when I type a long line. I added some screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to surround each «invisible» color code with special «marks»: `\001` and `\002`:

```
options(prompt = "\001\033[0;31m\002This is red\001\033[0m\002> ")
```

---

for explanation see `$ info readline` (or [this short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9468954/4827341)).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer that old question (currently with R version 3.6.0 and readline 8.0, do not know which matters, most of the above problems already disappeared, but your solution is really the way to go).

Answer (score 0):

Gábor Csárdi on the r-devel mailing list says that I cannot easily change this behavior (http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/buggy-ANSI-escape-sequences-in-R-prompt-td4728671.html). The workaround he proposes is to use a two lines prompt, which suits me well enough.