# Changing the colour of the prompt in R on ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu

Does anyone know if it is possible to change the colour of the prompt in an interactive R session in the ubuntu terminal?

I am aware that it is possible to change the prompt text using `options(prompt = 'new_prompt_text')` but I haven't been able to find anyway to change the colour. Currently the prompt, written commands, and output from each command are all the same colour, which is very hard to read. If anyone could suggest a way to change the colour of any of these that would be very helpful.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [https://github.com/jalvesaq/colorout](https://github.com/jalvesaq/colorout)

Comment: Yeah that works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: use (almost) standard terminal color codes. see [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42072092/4827341)

Answer (score 0):

I am using a bold pink prompt by using ANSI escape codes:
`options(prompt = "\001\033[0;35m\002>\001\033[0m\002 ")`

Surrounding every ANSI escape with `\001` and `\002` is necessary to fix some bugs (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42072092/buggy-ansi-escape-sequences-in-r-prompt)).