# Some characters stick to my colorized prompt in Python cmd

Tags: python, colors, command-line-interface, python-2.x, readline

I am using [Python 2's cmd module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) to make a command line for a program.  Everything works nicely as long as I don't add color to my prompt.

Working code:

```
from cmd import Cmd

class App(Cmd):

    def __init__(self):
        Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.prompt = "PG ["+ (str('username'), 'green') +"@"+ str('hostname') +"]: "

    def do_exit(self, line):
        '''
        '''
        return True

App().cmdloop()
```

When I change my code as below, if I enter a long command or try to search in the command history, some characters stick to my prompt.

Problem code:

```
from cmd import Cmd

class App(Cmd):

    def __init__(self):
        Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.prompt = "PG ["+ self.colorize(str('username'), 'green') +"@"+ str('hostname') +"]: "

    colorcodes =    {'green':{True:'\x1b[32m',False:'\x1b[39m'}}


    def colorize(self, val, color):
        return self.colorcodes[color][True] + val + self.colorcodes[color][False]

    def do_exit(self, line):
        '''
        '''
        return True

App().cmdloop()
```

You can see this problem in [asciicasts](https://asciinema.org/a/3phlotyufl6bl8hink8upxo7b).  The problem also exists with the [cmd2 module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cmd2/0.7.0).

Comment: @cxw Yes, It's Python2 and `cmd` but this problem exists in `cmd2` too!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add markers to your color codes:

```
    colorcodes =    {'green':{True:'\x01\x1b[32m\x02',False:'\x01\x1b[39m\x02'}}
                                  # ^^^^        ^^^^         ^^^^        ^^^^
```

In your asciicast, you have problems when you leave i-search mode and the prompt is re-printed.  That is because Python doesn't know that the escape characters don't actually take up space on the screen.  Putting `\x01` before each escape sequence, and `\x02` after each escape sequence, tells Python to assume those characters take up no space, and so the prompt will be correctly reprinted.

This is the same solution as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9468954/2877364), which had the corresponding problem in a different context.  There is an [open issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue17337#msg184246) to mention this in the Python readline documentation, but I don't see that it has yet been done.

I tested the above `colorcodes` values with Python 2.7.12 on Cygwin, running in mintty.  In the prompt, `username` printed green and everything else printed the default (light gray).  I used the standard system `cmd` module, *not* `cmd2` (which you linked).

Comment: Thank you so much! I had this issue with a `readline`-based interface and it was driving me nuts. I ended up with some ugly workaround of including some parts of my coloured prompt in `print()` with `end=''` and some in `input()`. This answer was exactly what I was looking for, but could not find when I needed it.