# How to colorise the Python repl

Tags: python, unix, vim, read-eval-print-loop, cpython

[image: python Repl]

[image: Vim]

As we can see the difference between the images. In vim datatype and function are of different color. How can i bring color to my python repl.

I want to do it by myself. Please suggest me, how should I do this. Whether I should have to do something with stdout stream object or I have to change something in python interpreter and then build it from source (ohh I have to compile the python from source only to bring this change)

Sorry if there is some error in my question. Hopes you all will understand me.

Comment: Take a look at [bpython](https://bpython-interpreter.org/), which does almost exactly that. You can take a look at the source to see how they do it (they also provide a list of similar [alternatives](https://bpython-interpreter.org/alternatives.html)).

Comment: Thanks @larsks. I will check it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Python interactive prompt ">>>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683744/change-python-interactive-prompt)

Answer (score 3):

You should probably have searched a little bit more first, because there are many answers here about this. Perhaps the best ones are:

- [bpython](https://github.com/bpython/bpython) [NOT on Windows without hack.]
- [ipython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython)
- [Change Python interactive prompt ">>>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683744/change-python-interactive-prompt/55924858#55924858)
- [Some characters stick to my colorized prompt in Python cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304113/some-characters-stick-to-my-colorized-prompt-in-python-cmd?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Adding colors in python interpreter prompt, does not wrap properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953812/adding-colors-in-python-interpreter-prompt-does-not-wrap-properly)
- [How to fix column calculation in Python readline if using color prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468435/how-to-fix-column-calculation-in-python-readline-if-using-color-prompt/9468954#9468954)

Comment: `ptpython` is another good option