# Why can't I use colored prompt with python CMD module?

Tags: python

I am trying to use colored prompt for `cmd` module in python.

**prompt.py**

```py
from cmd import Cmd

from utils.data_types import Str

class Prompt(Cmd):
    def __init__(self):
        Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.prompt = "prompt ({}) > ".format(Str("home").red())

    def emptyline(self):
        pass
```

**data_types.py**

```py
class Str(str):
    def red(self):
        return "\033[31m{}\033[0m".format(self)

    def green(self):
        return "\033[32m{}\033[0m".format(self)

    def yellow(self):
        return "\033[33m{}\033[0m".format(self)

    def blue(self):
        return "\033[34m{}\033[0m".format(self)
```

with this code, if I keep typing in the prompt, if there is no space at the end it should go to a newline but it's overwriting the sameline.

[image: issue]

I looked into the `cmd.py` file, it using `input` method and `readline`. I thought it might the problem with `input` method, I tried the following it works fine, only when I using `cmd` module the prompt breaks.

```py
inp = input("prompt ({}) > ".format(Str("home").red()))
```

**Edited:**

I think the problem with `readline`, whenever I import `readline` the prompt breaks, if I don't import `readline` the prompt works fine. Is this a bug?

apparently not a bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue12972

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Look how to fix column calculation in Python readline if use color prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468435/look-how-to-fix-column-calculation-in-python-readline-if-use-color-prompt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out that it's not an issue with python. Rather, this is a quirk with how readline works...

[Look how to fix column calculation in Python readline if use color prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468435/look-how-to-fix-column-calculation-in-python-readline-if-use-color-prompt)

Color prompts need to be wrapped by RL_PROMPT_START_IGNORE and RL_PROMPT_END_IGNORE.